# Recieving error about invalid column after deleting a column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `LISTEN` where I deleted some unused columns. One of the deleted columns was named `idfilter`.

I dropped this column, but now I get an error 207 when I try to update a record in this table:

```
UPDATE listen 
SET filter = 'ereignis' 
WHERE idlisten = 1348;
```

The displayed error message is

> SQL error (207): Invalid column name 'idfilter'

As you can see the deleted column is not involved in the update statement. I checked if the deleted column was used in views and also deleted these views.

What could be the reason for this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Presumably you have an `UPDATE` trigger referencing the deleted column

Comment: Don't drop random columns unless you have previously at least searched for their usage in the expression dependancy and sys.sql_modules views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a trigger which references to the deleted column.